# Obtener lista dispositivos disponibles libreria tcpdump C

Tags: c, redes

Estoy intentando aprender a interactuar con librerías de `C` de `tcpdump`

[Documentacion de referencia de tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_findalldevs.3pcap.html)

Quiero ejecutar la rutina `pcap_findalldevs` pero no lo logro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>


int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    struct pcap_if_t **alldevsp;
    char *errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_findalldevs(**alldevsp,*errbuf);

}
```

Este es el error que obtengo:

```
➜  networkc cc test_pcap.c -o test_pcap
test_pcap.c: In function ‘main’:
test_pcap.c:14:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct pcap_if_t’
   14 |     pcap_findalldevs(**alldevsp,*errbuf);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
➜  networkc
```

Busco el tipico error `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` y veo que en los headers hay:

```
struct pcap_if {
    struct pcap_if *next;
    char *name;     /* name to hand to "pcap_open_live()" */
    char *description;  /* textual description of interface, or NULL */
    struct pcap_addr *addresses;
    bpf_u_int32 flags;  /* PCAP_IF_ interface flags */
};
```

y también

```
typedef struct pcap_if pcap_if_t;
```

Por el típico mensaje de error `deferencing pointer` pienso que la estructura no esta creada. Voy a por la otra `pcap_if`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>


int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   struct pcap_if **alldevsp;
//    printf("%d", **alldevsp);
   char *errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

   pcap_findalldevs(**alldevsp,*errbuf);

}
```

Entonces obtengo otro error

```
test_pcap.c: In function ‘main’:
test_pcap.c:15:22: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘pcap_findalldevs’
   15 |     pcap_findalldevs(**alldevsp,*errbuf);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      struct pcap_if
In file included from test_pcap.c:6:
/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h:519:31: note: expected ‘pcap_if_t **’ {aka ‘struct pcap_if **’} but argument is of type ‘struct pcap_if’
  519 | PCAP_API int pcap_findalldevs(pcap_if_t **, char *);
```

Entiendo que `alldevsp` es una estructura tipo `pcap_if_t` y que tiene que ser una lista, por eso hay un doble puntero, pero no logro encontrar información de como interactuar.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás entendiendo correctamente los argumentos que la función espera:

> If `pcap_findalldevs( )` succeeds, the pointer pointed to by alldevsp is set to point to the first element of the list, or to `NULL` if no devices were found ...

*pointer pointed*, es decir, *puntero apuntado*. El primer argumento ha de ser la dirección de un puntero, que se rellenará con la dirección del primer elemento de la lista:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

int main( ) {
    pcap_if_t *item; /* <-  AQUÍ */
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_findalldevs( &item, errbuf );

    while( item ) {
        printf( "%s\n", item->name );
        item = item->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Trauma.  Añado informacion para otro usario si lo necesita. pcap se trata da una shared library, al compilarse hay que incorporarla: gcc test_pcap.c -o test_pcap -lpcap